# How to get rid of necessarily reloading in RSpec?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rspec, rspec-rails

I encountered a strange behavior when I run specs.

This code doesn't work (`baz.viewed` is not updated) unless I uncomment line `baz.reload`.

```
describe "#..." do
  it "..." do
    baz = user.notifications.create!(title: "baz")
    baz.update_attribute(:created_at, Time.now + 3.day)

    # it sets `viewed` to `true` in the model to which `baz` is referred.
    user.dismiss_latest_notification!

    # baz.reload
    baz.viewed.should == true
  end
end
```

I don't run specs using `Spork` or `Guard`, but this model isn't reloaded anyway.

Why it might happening? Or, is it normal practice to invoke `.reload` methods in specs?

Comment: This is normal. You should call `reload` when updating attributes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let me make this case a bit clearer for you:
When the line `baz = user.notifications.create!(title: "baz")` gets executed, two things happen:

1- A new notification row is added to the DB.

2- An object is created in memory, representing this row, and may be referenced with the variable `baz`.
Note that `baz` has a viewed value of false (and so does the row in the meantime).

Now I didn't see the actual implementation of the method

```
user.dismiss_latest_notification!
```

But since you are not passing any variable to it I surely know you have a code in the spirit of:

```
def dismiss_latest_notification!
  latest_notification = self.notifications.last
  latest_notification.viewed = true
  latest_notification.save!
end
```

The important line here is

```
   latest_notification = self.notifications.last
```

An object is created in memory, representing the same row `baz` does, but stored in another variable - latest_notification.

Now you have two variables representing the same row in DB. When you perform the save on latest_notification the DB is updated with the right viewed value but the variable `baz` is not updated in any manner to reflect this change. You have no choice but to force the update from the DB with the latest values by executing `reload` on it.

I think the right way to get rid of the reloading is to change the test a little bit:

Instead of

```
baz.viewed.should == true
```

Use:

```
user.notifications.last.viewed.should be_true
```

In my opinion, it better suits the purpose of this specific test.